# Response error in api call with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I want to retrieve the `houseType` and this is the api call using ajax. Only `Console.log` for `result` is fine but the others show `undefined`. I don't know why it happens.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api/get.php',
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    datatype:'json',
    data:{
      HouseNo: 2001
    },
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
      console.log(result.error);
      console.log(result.houses);
      console.log(result.houses.houseType);
      if (result.error == false) {
      window.location.href = "viewHouses.php"
    }
  },
  error: function(result) {
      alert("Error");
  }
});
```

The console log `result` is

```
{"error":false,"houses":[{"houseType":"Mansion"}]}
```

but the logs of `result.error` and `result.houses` are `undefined`. What am I missing?

Comment: what version of jquery you are using ?

Comment: housetype is result.houses[0].houseType because houses is an array

Comment: @Ashvin777It is 3.2.1.

Comment: But `result.error` log should show `false`. It shows `undefined`.

Comment: just comment the three lines if (result.error == false) {
      window.location.href = "viewHouses.php"
    } and try again

Comment: Commented and tried. It never goes to `if (result.error == false) { window.location.href = "viewHouses.php" } ` @MarouenMhiri

Comment: ok then can you try doing this? instead of all console.logs: for (var prop in result) { console.log(result[prop]);} and see what console logs

Comment: Are you requesting the data cross-origin?

Comment: It works with the logs { " e r r o r ......... @MarouenMhiri

Comment: I'm not but I just put cross-origin just in case. @JeffreyWesterkamp

Comment: please write the complete log of console.log(result[prop]) or just make a fiddle, it's hard to debug so

Comment: It shows `{"error":false,"houses":[{"houseType":"Mansion"}]}` in vertical align one word at a time. @MarouenMhiri

Comment: ok what shows console.log(typeof result) ? I bet it will be  string

Comment: The log shows string.

Comment: okay we got it now! just add result = JSON.parse(result) before all your console.log in your example

Comment: Thanks @MarouenMhiri. Can you just give an answer for me to accept?

Comment: That's okay! i see @JeffreyWesterkamp made a good one! It's always important to know the steps to debug! glad i could help ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the jquery docs state:

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript
>   object. Cross-domain "json" requests are converted to "jsonp" unless
>   the request includes jsonp: false in its request options. The JSON
>   data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and
>   a parse error is thrown.

If you are requesting the data with a cross-origin request, the options should have a `jsonp: false` value:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api/get.php',
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    datatype:'json',
    jsonp: false,

    data:{
        HouseNo: 2001
    },

    success: function(result) {
        // ...
    },

    error: function(result) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

To me this looks like you're actually logging a JSON(P) string of some sort. If the above does not work try parsing `result` with:

```
try {
    var parsed = JSON.parse(result);
    console.log(parsed);
} catch(err) { console.log(err); }
```

I'm curious what this snippet would log.

Comment: Sorry Jeffrey. I didn't realise your answer is nice. I accepted yours.

Comment: well explained!!

Comment: No problem at all, glad we could help you out! :)